# Create a two column content

Tags: plugins

I'm using the 2017 theme. I'm trying to set up a simple website where a user is able to easily add a photo with accompanying text (description).
The uploaded content should appear on one page where the photo will be in one column and the description (not caption - it's longer than just a caption) will be displayed on the 2nd column.

Please advise.

Comment: What had you tried and how far you got? This might depend a lot on how do you implement users, their uploads, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

just use a front-end page builder it will make your life easier.
forge is one exemple
https://wordpress.org/plugins/forge/

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved using Advanced Custom Fileds plugin.
1. Split your content area into in "single.php", by modifying css, you may need introduce new div tag.
2. Add ACF plugin and add filed, add this inside php.

```
the_field('your_filedname');
```

setup your field in plugin setup page.